# Correct way to set up Github repo in Pydev?

Tags: git, pydev

What is the correct way to set up a Github located repository of a Pydev project?

I usually do:

- create Pydev project
- share Pydev project to local folder
- create empty project on Github
- Push to Github (with EGit)

The issues I encounter are:

- Why is the project in some `Git` directory now, instead of my Eclipse Workspace now?
- Why do I get double nested directory structure like: `Git\Project`, `Git\Project\.git`, `Git\Project\Project\.project`? Is this correct?
- Should I check in the `.project` and `.pydevproject` file? If I don't, I get a mess when cloning on a new computer. If I do, I get complains about incorrect path configuration, when I check out to a new computer.
- Also it remains a mystery to me how and when I manage to configure the remote being tracked, rather than specifying the destination every time again.
- How can I correctly clone the repository to a new computer and use it as a Pydev project in Eclipse?

Answer (score 4):

I would normally start a new project by importing from Github. i.e. First create an empty repository at Github and then in Eclipse do

File -> Import -> Git -> Projects from Git

Once this is complete use the New Projects wizard to define a new PyDev Project with your repo. You will then have a clone of the github repo and be able to commit changes to github.

The Project should now have the same name as the repository on github.

EDIT: You can check in the .pydev and .pydevproject files.

In order to check out this project on a new computer you would follow these steps again - or export your eclipse environment and copy that to the new computer. For the sake of training yourself in eclipse and git it would probably be a good exercise to follow the above steps.

Comment: Actually, it's recommended that you check in .pydevproject and .project if you're working with a PyDev project... things there should be computer-independent (if they rely on some external directory you can use substitution variables to make it independent and configure those at the interpreter level).

Comment: Also, if you commit the .project and .pydevproject files, later on you can clone it anywhere and use the file > import > existing projects without any issues (otherwise you have to create a new project using that given place as the sources, which works but is not as streamlined).

Answer (score 0):

My project was already cloned for Git. To fix the issue I had to open the Git perspective and had my repository.